# How to call two different javascript/jquery functions on same HTML control(text field) on two different events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

Following is the HTML code I'm having for textfield on which the functions are written:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" size="20" onblur="GetLocation();"  id="zip_code" name="zip_code" value="">

<input type="text" class="form-control" size="20" readonly="readonly"    id="store_longitude" name="store_longitude" value="">

<input type="text" class="form-control" size="20" readonly="readonly"    id="store_latitude" name="store_latitude" value="">

<input type="text" class="form-control"  name="state_code" id="state_code" value="" size="20">

<input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" name="city" id="city" value="">
```

The jQuery/Javascript code are as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/*jQuery code for autopo-populate city and state when customer enters valid zip code*/
  $("#zip_code").keyup(function() {
    var el = $(this);                   
    if (el.val().length === 5) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: "zip=" + el.val(),
        success: function(result, success) {
          $("#city").val(result.city);
          $("#state_code").val(result.state);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

function GetLocation() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var saddress = $("#store_address").val();
    var store_state = $("#store_state").val();
    var store_country = $("#store_country").val();
    var store_zipcode = $("#store_zipcode").val();

    var complete_address = saddress +","+ store_state +","+ store_country +","+ store_zipcode;
    //alert(complete_address);
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': complete_address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            //alert(longitude);
            $("#store_longitude").val(longitude);
            $("#store_latitude").val(latitude);
        } else {
            alert("Request failed.")
        }
    });
 };
```

Can you please guide me how should I call both of the above functions when the textfield for zip code loses it's focus i.e. after filling the value(zip code) in this textfield both the above functions should get called?
Can someone please guide me in this regard please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok lets do this: Change in your js

```
function GetLocation() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var saddress = $("#store_address").val();
    var store_state = $("#store_state").val();
    var store_country = $("#store_country").val();
    var store_zipcode = $("#store_zipcode").val();

    var complete_address = saddress +","+ store_state +","+ store_country +","+ store_zipcode;
    //alert(complete_address);
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': complete_address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            //alert(longitude);
            $("#store_longitude").val(longitude);
            $("#store_latitude").val(latitude);
        } else {
            alert("Request failed.")
        }
    });
 $("#zip_code").keyup(function() {
    var el = $(this);                   
    if (el.val().length === 5) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: "zip=" + el.val(),
        success: function(result, success) {
          $("#city").val(result.city);
          $("#state_code").val(result.state);
        }
      });
    }
  });
 }
```

Now on your Focus OUT as:

```
$( "#zip_code" ).focusout(function() {
       GetLocation();
  })
```

Comment: It's not working for me. The Getlocation() function is not working. Can you please correct the code?

Comment: `$( "#zip_code" ).focusout(GetLocation);` No need to wrap that in an anonymous function.